# 405 Method not allowed RHF + Server Actions in Next.js and deploying it in Vercel

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel, react-hook-form, server-action

I watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VLk45JBe8L8) and everything works in dev and local, but I deployed the proyect in vercel and everytime I want to submit the form I get the 405 method not allowed. There are no logs about the error.

```js
const ref = useRef<HTMLFormElement>(null)
...
...
<form
  onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(()=>ref.current?.submit())}
  action={logInAction}
  ref={ref}
/>
```

I have tried only working with the action, but then i can't validate the data on the client side. I would like to preserve the same behavior of the video

Answer (score 0):

Update your question to include the defenition of `logInAction`

When using `action={...}` you must not use `onSubmit`. If you'd like to validate the data using React Hook Form, you can make like this

```
const ref = useRef<HTMLFormElement>(null)

const action = async (formData: FormData) => {
  const isValid = await form.trigger();

  if (!isValid) return;

  await logInAction(formData);
}

<form
  action={action}
  ref={ref}
/>
```

1. Remove `onSubmit` prop.
2. Call `trigger` to validate the values.

Comment: The definition of the login action is not relevant to the question, that's why it's not included. Thanks for the answer, I'll try it 